# Creating Excel Files with # in Column Name

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, xls, xlsx

I'm having problem creating Excel files using Jet. When I create a table and give it a Column name as

```
CreateTable [Sheet1] ([ColumnName#] String)
```

It replaces the header column with

```
ColumnName.
```

Is there a way I can make excel give the column headers a name with out any conflict in what characters I can have in it? Are there any escape characters that I can use in the column names?

Is there a cheap(~$50)/free .NET library that would give me better control over the Excel file that would allow me to create both XLS and XLSX files with out having excel installed?

Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is having a DataTable get dumped into an Excel File and have the Column names appear just as they do in the in the DateTable.

Comment: How are you creating Excel files using Jet?

Comment: I'm using Jet for creating the XLS files and ACE for creating XLSX files.

Comment: Which version of Jet? It has been a long time since I did this, but I seem to remember that Jet can not do this. Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: From Access 2003 Help: The Microsoft Jet database engine does not support the use of CREATE TABLE, or any of the DDL statements, with non-Microsoft Jet database engine databases.

Comment: I've been using Create Table with JET with out any problems aside from not having # in the column name.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried NPOI?

[NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I played around with it. It works good only thing is it is lacking XLSX support.

Answer (score 0):

Use **SpreadSheet XML (XMLSS)**. Lots of support for it including numerous sample code, documentation, and libraries. The best feature is its ease of use.

MSDN Library search for XMLSS at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=xmlss.

Comment: any chance you can provide some links and references - my googlefu is not up to scratch..

Comment: @Ahmad: I provided the proper search keywords in bold so that anyone can search to find revelant links and articles to their specific needs, but I will include an MSDN Library search link.